# Change a part of the span text using a bookmarklet javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, edit, html

recently I've asked a question on how to change a span's text via javascript ,

and the answer was

```
javascript:void(document.getElementById("serverTime").innerHTML = "...");
```

Now I want to change this span : `<span id="serverTime">5:46:40</span>`

into this one `<span id="serverTime">3:46:40</span>`

and no , not just editing the whole span and using the previous code , just editing a part of the span .

If that's possible though , I don't have an idea.

Comment: Do you always want to change it to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to change the `span`s text, then you can use replace:

```
javascript: (function (doc) {
    var sTime = doc.getElementById("serverTime"); 
    sTime.innerHTML = sTime.innerHTML.replace('5', '3');
})(document); // Remove spaces when bookmarking.
```

Comment: **Edited**: I'd forgotten to return void.